# ADB connecton to Android TV / Nvidia Shield TV?

Tags: android, adb, nvidia, android-tv

I try to send ADB commands from my Android mobile device (SGS5) to my Android TV (Nvidia Shield TV). I always get:

```
    error:device offline
```

or

```
    error:device unauthorized
```

With Windows or Mac the ADB connection works but not with an Android device.

I did the following:

- Disable/enable debug mode
- Used USB cable
- Used Wifi
- rebooted all devices
- adb kill-server / adb start-server
- adb usb

No success.

Is it possible to connect an Android device (mobile/tablet) over ADB with Android TV (e.g Nvidia Shield TV) ?

Mobile phone -> adb -> Shield TV

Comment: So it looks like connecting from a Android device to a Android TV via ADB is not possible due to security restrictions. Sad :-(

Answer (score 2):

For Nvidia Shield TV, you would need to

1. Enable usb debugging on Nvidia Shield TV
2. Connect Nvidia Shield to your machine with usb cable
3. Do `adb devices` => device should get listed. You would need to check and accept authorization screen
4. Note ip address of device under System -> Network Settings
5. Do `adb tcpip <port_no>`
6. Unplug usb cable
7. `adb connect <ip_address from step 4>`

`Note`: This should ideally be one time process, however there are times when device goes offline when adb action is not performed for long. Possible solutions are

a. Repeat steps 1-7 above

or

b. Set up a job (like cron) which will perform some periodic action on device.
Example: `adb shell input keyevent 25`.

Comment: Thanks but this is the solution for PC or Mac but not for an Android device. As I wrote in my question I try to send ADB commands from my Android mobile device (SGS5) to my Android TV (Nvidia Shield TV). When I plug it in with usb cable there is no authorization screen showing up. With Windows or Mac the ADB connection works but not with an Android device.
Did you try your solution with an Android device? How to do it with an Android device?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your question properly. Afaik, you will get authorization prompt only if `adb client` is running. On android device `adbd server` runs. So, I don't think this is possible. If you are able push `adb client` into SGS4 then it might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you try all of them then try last one its working for me
- Check mobile ip and in about phone and try below command

```
adb connect 192.168.1.4:2222
```

[Check this link for more details](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

And also not working then try below
Turn on ADB Debugging

You must enable ADB on the  Fire TV device before you can connect to the device.

```
From the main (Launcher) screen, select Settings.
Select System > Developer Options.
Select ADB Debugging.
```

Get the IP Address

You need the IP address of your Fire TV device on your network to connect ADB to it.

```
From the main (Launcher) screen, select Settings.
Select System > About > Network. Make note of the IP address listed on this screen.
```

Connect ADB

To connect your development computer to a Fire TV device, use the following steps:

```
Open a command prompt or terminal window.
Change directory to your Android SDK platform-tools directory.
Run the following commands, where <ipaddress> is the IP address of the Fire TV device noted in the previous section.

adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb connect <ipaddress>

Note: On Mac OS X and Linux you may need to prepend ./ to these commands, like this:

./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
./adb connect <ipaddress>


If the connection was sucessful, ADB responds with the message:
connected to <ipaddress>:5555

Verify that the Fire TV device appears in the list of devices:

adb devices


ADB reponds responds with the message:

List of devices attached
<ipaddress>:5555  device
```

Comment: Thanks but with Amazon Fire TV I have no ptoblems. Connection and other commands work fine. My problem is on pure Android TV , like Nvidia Shield TV. Did you get it to work on Shield TV?

Comment: no dear i use android mini pc and in android mini pc working properly